# Is it possible to programmatically select the text of a textfield in a UIAlertView?

Tags: ios, select, uitextfield, uialertview

I would like to automatically select text that I add to a `UIAlertView`. I thought this would work but it doesn't:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:...];
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

UITextField *tf = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
tf.text = @"Some text";

[tf selectAll:nil];
```

Comment: It may look more professional to have a copy to clipboard button in the alert view if the point to this is to make it possible for the user to copy the contents of the alert message. You can do this with the UIPasteboard class I think.

Comment: In my use-case it would be best if I could programmatically select all of the text in an an UIAlertView's text field.